# MySQL Deadlock On 2 Updates

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

We've been receiving some deadlocks and this our latest `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

### Query 1:

```
UPDATE actions SET
    hv_clientid='56c46db2dd',
    hv_clientid_time=NOW(),
    hv_lastcheck=NOW() 
WHERE 
    hv_callid!=''
    AND is_done='N'
    AND (hv_lastcheck
        BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
        AND DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 120 SECOND)
    OR hv_lastcheck='0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    AND (
        hv_clientid IS NULL
        OR (
            hv_clientid_time IS NOT NULL
            && hv_clientid_time<DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
        )
    )
LIMIT 60
```

### Query 2:

```
UPDATE actions SET
    hv_clientid=NULL,
    result='answer',
    is_done='Y',
    hv_callid=''
WHERE action_id='145291132'
```

We have multiple instances of a script that checks for statuses to update.  *Query 1* should grab rows, which it then selects based on the `hv_clientid` that is set.  Once that select iterates over the data it runs *Query 2*.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Please show your schema (indexes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MySQL Documentation - 14.2.7.9 How to Cope with Deadlocks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) (highlight added):

> When **modifying** multiple tables within a transaction, or **different
>   sets of rows in the same table**, do those operations in a consistent
>   order each time. Then transactions form well-defined queues and do not
>   deadlock. For example, organize database operations into functions
>   within your application, or call stored routines, rather than coding
>   multiple similar sequences of INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements in
>   different places.

If this is the cause, adding an `ORDER BY` clause to *Query 1* should help.